# How do I make two images start moving when a button is pushed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to race two cars when a button is pushed. I want them to move at different speeds.

I am using startRaceButton.onClick to run my two start race functions which set intervals for my images to move. I also have it set to clear the interval after it reaches the finish line.

The problem I am having is, when the button is clicked nothing happens.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var redSpeed = 1*(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            var blueSpeed = 1*(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            var blueLeft = 81;
            var redLeft = 81;
            var redInterval = 10;
            var blueInterval = 10;
            var redTimer;
            var blueTimer;
            var startRaceButton = document.getElementById("imgStartButton");
            var redCar = document.getElementById("imgRedCar");
            var blueCar = document.getElementById("imgBlueCar");

            var goRed = function() {
                redCar.style.left = redLeft + "px";
                redLeft += redSpeed;
                if (redLeft > 899) {
                    clearInterval(redTimer);
                    }
                }
            var goBlue = function() {
                blueCar.style.left = blueLeft + "px";
                blueLeft += blueSpeed;
                if (blueLeft > 899) {
                    clearInterval(blueTimer);
                    }
                }

            var startRed = function() {
                redTimer = setInterval(goRed, redInterval);
                }

            var startBlue = function() {
                blueTimer = setInterval(goBlue, blueInterval);
                }

            startRaceButton.onclick = function() {
                startRed();     
                startBlue();
                }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style= "display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:1005px; height:400px;" id="container">
        <div id="left" style= "float:left; display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:80px; height:400px">
            <img id="imgStartButton" src="http://ondemandweb.pbworld.net/pbucontent/images/GOButton.jpg" width="60" height="60" >
        </div>
        <div id="box" style="float:left; display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:920px; height:400px;">
            <img id="imgBlueCar" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTxJr8SKga0S-nM4JgzlIXk6XrmgN8fwdDbvA6tKGWV65fmeaYWDA" style="position:absolute; left:81px; top:100px" width="100" height="60" alt="blue">
            <img id="imgRedCar" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8nsZ52wkuxrlT3aiqFicu_YYOVJ1hSKCI2-0MY6G4QKSGHIj4tw" style="position:absolute; left:81px; top:250px" width="100" height="60" alt="red">
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="float:left; display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:5px; height:400px; background-color:black; ">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script is running before your DOM loads. Therefore your bindings don't have meaning.

try including the script after the body of your html.

Comment: Hell yea! Thank you, that was it.

Comment: glad it worked! is there anything else you need? if not, can you accept my answer :)

Comment: do you have a suggestion for how to alert the winner of the cars?

Comment: a basic approach could be to use an if statement to check if one car reaches the "finish line" alert something etc, else execute that alert or something for the other car